# Twitter Bootstrap Modal Shows Up on Initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

### JS

```
 $('#CreateUserModal').modal({
     keyboard: true,
     backdrop: 'static'
 });
```

### HTML

```
<div id="CreateUserModal" class="modal fade hide">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("Partials/CreateUserPartial", new CreateUserModel());}
</div>
```

### The Partial

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateUser", "User", null, options, new { style = "margin-bottom:0;" }))
{
    <div style="padding: 20px;">
    <div style="text-align: right; font-size: .7em;">Press Esc to Close</div>
    <h2>New User</h2>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions" style="margin-bottom:0;">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
}
```

For some reason, as soon as this page loads the modal pops up.  I can dismiss it and everything works fine.  I would just expect it to start out hidden.  I recently upgraded to the latest bootstrap and that is when I noticed this issue.

Ideas?

Comment: Took me forever to understand this (I'm new to bootstrap).  But you don't need to initialize any modal in your script code unless you want to customize a modal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isn't this code:

```
 $('#CreateUserModal').modal({
     keyboard: true,
     backdrop: 'static'
 });
```

opening your modal?
I thought you only needed to call the modal-function when you wanted the modal to popup?

**UPDATE**

If you inspect the twitter bootstrap javascript for the modal, it confirms that upon creation it opens the modal:

```
 $.fn.modal = function ( option ) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('modal')
        , options = typeof option == 'object' && option
      if (!data) $this.data('modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
      else data.show()
    })
  }
```

I guess you can tweak this a bit, but the toggle/hide is if you already have a modal created I presume.

In your code I would rather just go with the html-markup method:

```
<a class="btn fade" data-toggle="modal" href="#CreateUserModal" >Launch Modal</a>
```

That will do all the boilerplate for you, providing a link which launches the modal.

Answer (score 13):

For Bootstrap 2.0

Set the "show" option to false like this.

```
$('#myModal').modal({show: false});
```

Yngve B. Nilsen's is correct that the after initialization modal opens by default.
[See bootstrap modal documenation under options](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)

Comment: This is the better answer in terms of getting the dialog not to display on init.

Answer (score 8):

This works in ff:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide">...</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a new modal from its constructor, then you have **ultimate** control and can manipulate the modal object as you please.

```
// Create a new modal object
var modal = new $.fn.modal.Constructor();

// Set whatever defaults you want
$.fn.modal.defaults = { show: true, backdrop: 'static' };
$('#your_el').modal()
  .show()
  .on('hide', function() {
    callbackFunction();
  });
```